# GH-pages don't load default route

Tags: reactjs, routes, github-pages

I added my first simple react project to GH pages.

Localy, when I used

```
<Route exact path='/' element= { <Home />} />
```

After running app it redirects me to `/Home` route. Don't know how achieve this in `ghpages`, tried to add name of repo, or what links show, but didn't work.

Would be appreciate for help :)

```
{

        <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/NailsByEc' element={<Home />} />
        <Route
          path='/NailsByEc/?fbclid=IwAR0fesoX_SkuQoA2kgz70b9fXx7kC6FjDDGDGjp39AIj_ZDDKPrpl3MZuAE'
          element={<Home />}
        />
        <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/gallery' element={<Gallery />} />
        <Route path='/offer' element={<Offer />} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
}
```

https://lcse1706.github.io/NailsByEc

Comment: GHPages only supports the hash router since there is no catch all routes setup in their servers. You will need to use https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#hashrouter

Comment: Thank You Dominik, it works :)